# How to load list of images using spring boot and show in html

Tags: spring

How to fetch list of images from server and show then in web page.

I have 1000+ images of different product and I want to build feature where user can select the category of product and based on product category I want to fetch all images from server and want to show to user for his selection.

Kindly let me know how to do it using spring/spring boot and angular js.

Comment: What do you have so far? Any research at all?

Comment: I have created spring boot simple application. I thought of putting images in static folder to serve in html page. Not sure why images places inside "static" folder in spring boot is not accessible to me. I know that By default, Spring Boot serves static content from a directory called /static. Still it is not working in my case. I need to something to handle the images present in static folder ?

Comment: Yes, images are best put into a static directory, under `src/resources/static/`. You can then process the images and return them as `MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE` via a `@RestController` and display it with your angular frontend.

Comment: If I am putting them in src/resources/static/ folder then I can directly access it without going to controller right ?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to save the image in a storage such as amazon S3, then save the url on your application, when you need to show you just put the url in your html tag

```
<img src="s3url"/>
```